# Android studio Lost connection to device

Tags: flutter, combinations

I have an issue where i am running this code and getting all different combinations of the number without repeating.

It is put in a for loop where I have a list of numbers.

If the list is only of just 1 number, it seems to be alright. However when I have multiple numbers in the list, Android studio loses connection to my device.

Is it because my app is doing too much? If not how do I fix it?

```
List<String> rollNumberGenerator(String num) {
    List numberToBeRolled = num.split('');

    List<String> generatedRollList = [];

    String zero = numberToBeRolled[0];
    String one = numberToBeRolled[1];
    String two = numberToBeRolled[2];
    String three = numberToBeRolled[3];

    String rollNumber1 = '$zero$one$two$three';
    String rollNumber2 = '$zero$one$three$two';
    String rollNumber3 = '$zero$three$one$two';
    String rollNumber4 = '$three$zero$one$two';
    String rollNumber5 = '$three$zero$two$one';
    String rollNumber6 = '$zero$three$two$one';
    String rollNumber7 = '$zero$two$three$one';
    String rollNumber8 = '$zero$two$one$three';
    String rollNumber9 = '$two$zero$one$three';
    String rollNumber10 = '$two$zero$three$one';
    String rollNumber11 = '$two$three$zero$one';
    String rollNumber12 = '$three$two$zero$one';
    String rollNumber13 = '$three$two$one$zero';
    String rollNumber14 = '$two$three$one$zero';
    String rollNumber15 = '$two$one$three$zero';
    String rollNumber16 = '$two$one$zero$three';
    String rollNumber17 = '$one$two$zero$three';
    String rollNumber18 = '$one$two$three$zero';
    String rollNumber19 = '$one$three$two$zero';
    String rollNumber20 = '$three$one$two$zero';
    String rollNumber21 = '$three$one$zero$two';
    String rollNumber22 = '$one$three$zero$two';
    String rollNumber23 = '$one$zero$three$two';
    String rollNumber24 = '$one$zero$two$three';

    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber1);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber2);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber3);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber4);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber5);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber6);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber7);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber8);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber9);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber10);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber11);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber12);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber13);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber14);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber15);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber16);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber17);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber18);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber19);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber20);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber21);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber22);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber23);
    generatedRollList.add(rollNumber24);

    List<String> validGeneratedRollList = [];

    for (var numbers in generatedRollList) {
      bool present = false;
      present = validGeneratedRollList.contains(numbers);
      if (present == false) {
        validGeneratedRollList.add(numbers);
      }
    }
    return validGeneratedRollList;
  }
```

Thanks in advance for anyone that can help!

Comment: You are running on debug mode so sometime your app take all the resource that device have in debug mode. So you can run on release or profile mode in Run. It may help

Comment: I actually found out what was causing my crashes, I was having a lot of Firestore transactions going on. After I added await to my update.transactions, it seems that my app doesnt crash anymore!